# What should be `lap` when doing Bluez inquiry?

Tags: c, bluetooth, bluez

I am using this API:

https://github.com/bluez/bluez/blob/master/lib/hci.c#L970

```
int hci_inquiry(int dev_id, int len, int nrsp, const uint8_t *lap,
        inquiry_info **ii, long flags)
```

I can pass NULL in place of lap but if I do so, hard coded values will be used.

https://github.com/bluez/bluez/blob/master/lib/hci.c#L1005

```
    if (lap) {
        memcpy(ir->lap, lap, 3);
    } else {
        ir->lap[0] = 0x33;
        ir->lap[1] = 0x8b;
        ir->lap[2] = 0x9e;
    }
```

What do these hardcoded bytes means? What if I pass NULL? What if I pass random bytes? What should I pass? Should it be lap of the local device?

I tried passing NULL, random bytes and LAP of my local device. I see no difference in behavior but I assume it's not there for nothing.

Comment: Even though that project has over 15k commits, the last one was nearly 8 years ago. Looks dead to me. I recommend looking for something that was created around 14-OCT-2013 or contact the last committer.

Comment: @JeffHolt I apologize. I updated the links to point to a live repo.

Comment: The documented APIs for BlueZ are at: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc. The majority of them use D-Bus to communicate with the Bluetooth daemon (`bluetoothd`). If you want lower level control then there is user socket communication with `bluetoothd` using the [mgmt](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/mgmt-api.txt) API